# Attribute is not added in .each function

Tags: jquery

I have an issue with the below code. The console log in the .each loop correctly console the element with the attribute display none (i want it as custom attribute for my reasons, i dont want to hide anything). But when i am console log it before the return , the tables does not have the display none attribute. Any help please ?

```
var checkRules = function(deposit_row){
        $(deposit_row).filter('tr').children("td").children('table').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('display','none');
            console.log(this);
         });
      console.log(deposit_row);
      return deposit_row;
    };
```

I have made a DEMO to explain you what i mean . Look the second console log what it prints , the display none is not there https://jsfiddle.net/dmrtwwvt/

Comment: `$(this).css('display','none');`

Comment: `$(this).attr('style','display:none');` do this

Comment: check this using my code [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/dmrtwwvt/2/) it has style='display:none'

Comment: Look your 2nd console log on your demo. Can you find the property style ="display: none" ?

Comment: you are showing the variable in console not the updated one

Comment: What do you mean ? . Why its not updated ? This is actually my prob. Can you make a demo please for me ?.

Comment: first give a valid html on the sample. it is not a valid html from there make a jquery object and do sa i answer it will work

Comment: But the html is valid. This is exactly what i want to do. I paste only the necessary code because i have confidential data on the bank account etc

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/dnbrhpvr/)

> I dont want it for css reasons. I want to put it as custom attribute for my reasons

Use:

```
$(this).attr('style','display:none');
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefix your attribute

```
$(deposit_row).find('tr td table').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('data-display','none');
            console.log(this);
         });
```